Trying to create Instance from Horizon. But client denied by server configuration and Block Device Mapping is invalid and failed
I tried to create the instance from Horizon.But the server cannot be created. The following is the error log from apache2...
DEBUG novaclient.v2.client REQ: curl -g -i -X POST http://controller:8774/v2.1/servers -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "OpenStack-API-Version: compute 2.60" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA256}2ac706cb1e4e19eeb414255df32d44f8515dd7a13d77aa1620ae570199ea1076" -H "X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version: 2.60" -d '{"server": {"name": "TestInstance", "imageRef": "", "flavorRef": "0", "key_name": "xxx_laptop", "min_count": 1, "max_count": 1, "security_groups": [{"name": "e7bd6c22-e789-46c0-a1c0-b6756e73f39a"}, {"name": "85d01deb-bc4d-4649-acc0-780f4f466ecb"}], "availability_zone": "nova", "block_device_mapping_v2": [{"source_type": "image", "destination_type": "volume", "delete_on_termination": false, "uuid": "b89274d2-b871-42b0-b44f-e5902152bb73", "boot_index": "0", "volume_size": 1}], "networks": [{"uuid": "369e44fa-ae0f-47a7-a09e-5c18a92df788"}], "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO"}}'
[Mon Sep 30 16:06:16.396265 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 3806006:tid 140283471709952] [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:51450] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public
[Mon Sep 30 16:06:16.402290 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 3805994:tid 140283623089920] [remote xxx.xx.xx.xxx:50198] DEBUG novaclient.v2.client RESP: [400] Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 134 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2024 08:06:16 GMT Openstack-Api-Version: compute 2.60 Vary: OpenStack-API-Version, X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version X-Compute-Request-Id: req-73280771-79cb-4f55-a72b-ce3407c368d4 X-Openstack-Nova-Api-Version: 2.60 X-Openstack-Request-Id: req-73280771-79cb-4f55-a72b-ce3407c368d4
[Mon Sep 30 16:06:16.402659 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 3805994:tid 140283623089920] [remote xxx.xx.xx.xxx:50198] DEBUG novaclient.v2.client RESP BODY: {"badRequest": {"code": 400, "message": "Block Device Mapping is Invalid: failed to get image b89274d2-b871-42b0-b44f-e5902152bb73."}}
``


The error message already seems to contain all necessary information. You can additionally look into the nova-compute.log, cinder-volume.log and glance-api.log (or similar depending on your deployment). It appears that cinder might not be permitted to download images from glance. You'll need to check which projects have access to the image you provided.
